# What is the cause of JBoss error in logs: "Invalid URI character encoding; trying ascii"

Tags: java, apache, jakarta-ee, encoding, jboss

There is the next error from CoyoteAdapter that is being written to JBoss 7 production logs much often:

```
16:30:25,275 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] (http--0.0.0.0-8443-374) Invalid URI character encoding; trying ascii
```

Only that message and nothing more. I have no any success in reproducing such output, but it's a frequent situation on production.

JBoss' standalone.xml has encoding configuraion for connector as next:

```
<system-properties>
    <property name="org.apache.catalina.connector.URI_ENCODING" value="UTF-8"/>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION" value="on"/>
    <property name="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol.COMPRESSION_MIME_TYPES" value="text/html,text/xml,text/plain,text/css,application/x-javascript,text/javascript"/>
</system-properties>
```

What can cause such kind of error?

Comment: My *guess* is that some non-UTF-8 encoded data is passed via the URI.